# Cypress :WebPack Compilation Error: Despite of having all the required modules

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

[image]

I am trying to setup and install cypress in a project and i have installed cypress version 14.12.0
Node Version : 18.11.0
"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^18.0.0",
"@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.17.1",

const createBundler = require('@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor');
const addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin = require('@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin;
const createEsBuildPlugin = require('@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild').createEsbuildPlugin;
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
e2e: {

```
specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/features/*.feature',
stepDefinitions: "cypress/e2e/common/*.js",
"fixturesFolder": "cypress/fixtures",
supportFile: 'cypress/support/e2e.js',
setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  // implement node event listeners here
},
```

},
});

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you didn't finish reading the instructions - some of the modules you have imported are not used at all, and you misspelled one of them.

Here is the correct version, for CJS:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const createBundler = require('@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor')
const preprocessor = require('@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor')
const createEsBuildPlugin = require('@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/features/*.feature',
    stepDefinitions: 'cypress/e2e/common/*.js',    // this may be a problem!
    fixturesFolder: 'cypress/fixtures',
    supportFile: 'cypress/support/e2e.js',
    async  setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      await preprocessor.addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);
      on(
        "file:preprocessor",
        createBundler({
          plugins: [createEsBuildPlugin.default(config)],
        })
      );
      return config;
    },
  },
})
```